# function pointer - inside and outside a class

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

I'm a noob to function pointers and this is the first time I'm using it.

The code is:

```
#include "time.cpp"
int main(){
 double** matrix= new double*[10];
 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) matrix[i]=new double[10];
 gear nit;
 nit.roll(&matrix[0]);
}
```

time.cpp

```
double pulse_a (double t, double dt);

class gear{
        void dynamics(double (*)(double, double), double** , double, double);
        double pulse_b(double t, double dt);
public:
        int net;
        void roll(double** matrix);
};

void gear::roll(double** matrix){
        double t,dt;
        double (*pfunc)(double,double)=pulse_a; //or pulse_b
        dynamics(pfunc,&matrix[0],t,dt);
}

void gear::dynamics(double (*pulse)(double , double ), double** matrix, double t, double dt){

pulse(t,dt);
}
```

When I assign pfunc to pulse_a, I get

> error: argument of type ‘double (gear::)(double, double)’ does not match ‘double (*)(double, double)’

for             `double (*pfunc)(double,double)=pulse_a;`

When I assing pfunc to pulse_b, I get `undefined reference to chirp(double, double)'`
for             `double (*pfunc)(double,double)=pulse_b;`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have chosen a ridiculously complicated example for your first foray into function pointers. You should start with the simplest example you can come up with.

Your first pointer

```
double (*pfunc)(double,double)=pulse_a;
```

works as written. It doesn't produce the error you describe; I don't see how it could possibly produce the error you describe (since it doesn't involve `gear`), so I'll bet the code you posted is not the code that produced the error. Please don't do that.

A *pointer to a function* and a *pointer to a member function* are different animals. They have different types and are not interchangeable. Don't try to cast one to another or you'll be in violation of ancient tribal law (and you'll get undefined behavior).

```
void dynamics2(double (gear::*)(double, double), double** , double, double);
...
double (gear::*pfunc2)(double,double) = &gear::pulse_b;
dynamics2(pfunc2,&matrix[0],t,dt);
```

Once you've gotten the hang of these pointers, you can save yourself some headaches by means of `typedef`:

```
typedef double (gear::*gearMemFn)(double, double);
void dynamics2(gearMemFn, double** , double, double);
...
gearMemFn pfunc2=&gear::pulse_b;
```

Comment: This is the exact error:
/tmp/ccy2DvIL.o: In function 'gear::roll(double**)':
/home/user/dir/time.cpp:13: undefined reference to 'pulse_a(double, double)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm using, g++ version 4.5.1 20101208 (SUSE Linux)

Comment: And thanks for explaining about the details about member functions. It solves the thing.

Comment: It's ok. I had just declared the function, not defined it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use function pointers for anything. Use `std::function` like a normal person.

Also, member functions are not and can never be function pointers. It will have to be a static function.